# How to modify specific text in a specific line in a text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to modify specific words in a specific line so that the user can input which line they want to modify and which text they want to search and replace.

Here's my code:

```
def mod_apartment():
    a = []
    b = []
    with open("Apartment_Details.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            a = line.split(",")
            print(a)
    with open("Apartment_Details.txt", "r") as file:
        print("Enter line: ", end="")
        lno = int(input())
        lines = line[lno]
```

Output:

```
['0001', '  Trifolis', '  900SQFT', '  A-A-A Impiana', '  Taman Garden', '  Kajang', '  Selangor', '  Furnished', '  Ready', '  Apartment', '  RM1700', '  Freehold', '  7 August 2022', '  6 August 2022', '\n']
['0002', '  Sky Suites ', '  1000SQFT', '  Taman MingMing', '  Persinsin 2', '  Selangor', '  Kuala Lumpur ', '  Not Furnished ', '  Not Ready', '  Apartment', '  RM1000', '  Freehold ', '  10 November 2022', '  19 August 2022', '']
Enter line: 2
```

How do you append so that the user can modify line [0], and replace 0001 to 0003 for example.

Comment: you don't have to open file second time

Comment: `line[lno][0] = "0003"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to implement the desired functionality:

```py
# read all lines
with open("Apartment_Details.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

line_i = int(input("Enter line: "))
# only splitting the line here, because we don't need to split the others
words = lines[line_i].split(",")
print(words)

word_i = int(input("Enter word position: "))
new_word = input("Enter replacement: "))
# replace the entry in words => that does not reflect to lines
words[word_i] = new_word
# therefore, also update lines (recombining the splitted words)
lines[line_i] = ",".join(words)

# write back to the file
with open("Apartment_Details.txt", "w") as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

## Notes on your code

- no need to set `a = []` when overwriting it directly afterwards.
- only the last value (the last line) you store on a will be available after the `for` block
- you don't need the second `with`, you're not using the file. You need it of course when writing back to the file
- The `line` variable in the second `with` block is the last line in the file. It's "left over" from the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Is this ok for you?

```
def mod_apartment():
    a = []
    with open("Apartment_Details.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            b = line.split(",")
            print(b)
            a.append(b)
            
    lno = int(input("\nEnter line index: "))
    wdo = int(input("Enter word index: "))
    word = input("Replace with: ")
    a[lno][wdo] = word

    print("\nNew lines:")
    with open("Apartment_Details.txt", "w") as file:
        for line in a:
            print(line)
            file.write(','.join(line))
```

Here the user has to write the row and word indices, but if you want to change it to the numbers of these objects, just replace this line:

```
a[lno - 1][wdo - 1] = word
```